# Nodemcu enduser_setup how to let user set his Wifi credentials?

Tags: lua, nodemcu

If I wish to distribute a NodeMCU-based device, I would want my end user to set the Wifi password and then store it. I hope to secure the login using one of the schemes here: [How to prevent WiFi Password from being leaked from Lua code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243734/how-to-prevent-wifi-password-from-being-leaked-from-lua-code)

However, before that, the device needs to sign on to the user's network first.

I thought enduser.setup() would accomplish this per http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/enduser-setup/#enduser_setupmanual

But much as I've tried the various enduser_setup() options, I fail to see how the following instruction would work:

> After running enduser_setup.start() a portal like the above can be accessed through a wireless network called SetupGadget_XXXXXX.

I don't see "SetupGadget_XXXXXX" in the network.

What is the preferred solution?

Thanks!

Comment: `XXXXXX` is going to be a random number, keep that in mind.

Comment: Is this resolved? If so please consider [upvoting/accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer(s).

Comment: This is a big problem. The AP stops automatically once the STA IP is obtained from the home network (it does allow a guard time of 10 sec before the AP stops). After that, the module will save the STA IP. Now if you try to connect the module to a different Wi-Fi network, the end_user.setup() won't start the AP as there's already a saved station IP address. I've always relied on standard TCP server running on STA+AP mode.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be 100% sure but the most likely cause is this (quote from the docs):

> After an IP address has been successfully obtained this module will
>   stop as if enduser_setup.stop() had been called.

Your device probably used the WiFi credentials it used last time i.e. it remembers them. Therefore, it probably has an IP address if it's in the vicinity of a known AP.

You can reset the WiFi config by issuing e.g.

```
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.config("foo","") -- inexistent SSID
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar and I am able to figure out the issue. You have to make the custom build of NodeMCU firmware and make sure that you include "end user setup" module in the build. You can make the custom build from following link.

https://nodemcu-build.com/